# Por que mi pagina cuando esta en vista de movil tiene 60% de height?

Tags: html, css

Es una pagina de prueba que hice (una tienda) ya que estoy practicando html y css porque soy nuevo en esto de la programacion, cuando es en pantalla grande de 1020px o mas se ve bien pero en diseño de movil los contenedores de los productos se me ponen con un height al 60% por defecto y hacen que el contenedor que tiene los productose se vea excesivamente alargado, ya hice los cambios en el css y en local se ve bien pero cuando la web esta subida se sigue viendo con ese problema. alguna solucion? por mas que le cambie el height al archivo css se sigue visualizando con el height del 60%

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

http://free.zz.com.ve/

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tecnoven</title>
    <link  rel="icon"   href="favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles_grande.css" media="screen and (min-width:1000px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles_mini.css" media="screen and (max-width:999px)">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

        <header class="header-grande header-mini">
        
            <nav>
                <img class="logo-grande logo-mini" src="logo.png">

                <ul class="lista-nav-grande lista-nav-mini">
                    <li> <a href= #inicio > Inicio </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href= #productos > Productos </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href= #contacto > Contacto </a> </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <p class="siguenos-grande grande">Siguenos en nuestras redes!</p>

            <a class="logofb-grande grande" title="Perfil de Tecnoven en Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/DAGF1712">
                <img class="logofb-grande grande" src="logofb.png" alt="Perfil de Tecnoven en Facebook"> </a>

            <a class="logoig-grande grande" title="Perfil de Tecnoven en Instagram" href="http://www.instagram.com/DAGF1712">
                <img class="logoig-grande grande" src="logoig.png" alt="Perfil de Tecnoven en Instagram"> </a>

        </header>

        <main class="main-grande main-mini">

            <h2 class="productos-nuevos-grande productos-nuevos-mini">PRODUCTOS NUEVOS</h2>
            <h3 class="smartphones-grande smartphones-mini">Telefonos inteligentes</h3>

                        <div class="smartphone-grande smartphone-mini">
                <h3 class="titulo-smartphone-grande titulo-smartphone-mini">Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro</h3>

                <a class="foto-smartphone-grande foto-smartphone-mini" title="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro" href="#">
                <img class="foto-smartphone-grande foto-smartphone-mini" src="smartphone1.jpg" alt="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro"> </a>

                <table class="tabla-smartphone-grande grande">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ESPECIFICACIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Almacenamiento</td>
                            <td>32GB/64GB/128GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Memoria RAM</td>
                            <td>6GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara frontal</td>
                            <td>8 Megapixeles</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara trasera</td>
                            <td>4 camaras: 32mp,8mp,5mp,2mp</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="precio-smartphone-grande precio-smartphone-mini">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>230$</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <a class="comprar-smartphone-grande comprar-smartphone-mini" href="#">Comprar</a>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="smartphone-grande smartphone-mini">
                <h3 class="titulo-smartphone-grande titulo-smartphone-mini">Samsung Galaxy Note 10</h3>

                <a class="foto-smartphone-grande foto-smartphone-mini" title="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro" href="#">
                <img class="foto-smartphone-grande foto-smartphone-mini" src="smar2.jpg" alt="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro"> </a>

                <table class="tabla-smartphone-grande grande">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ESPECIFICACIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Almacenamiento</td>
                            <td>32GB/64GB/128GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Memoria RAM</td>
                            <td>6GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara frontal</td>
                            <td>8 Megapixeles</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara trasera</td>
                            <td>4 camaras: 32mp,8mp,5mp,2mp</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="precio-smartphone-grande precio-smartphone-mini">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>900$</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <a class="comprar-smartphone-grande comprar-smartphone-mini" href="#">Comprar</a>
                
            </div>
 <div class="smartphone-grande smartphone-mini">
                <h3 class="titulo-smartphone-grande titulo-smartphone-mini">Samsung Galaxy A50</h3>

                <a class="foto-smartphone-grande foto-smartphone-mini" title="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro" href="#">
                <img class="foto-smartphone-grande foto-smartphone-mini" src="smart.jpg" alt="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro"> </a>

                <table class="tabla-smartphone-grande grande">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ESPECIFICACIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Almacenamiento</td>
                            <td>32GB/64GB/128GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Memoria RAM</td>
                            <td>6GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara frontal</td>
                            <td>8 Megapixeles</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara trasera</td>
                            <td>4 camaras: 32mp,8mp,5mp,2mp</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="precio-smartphone-grande precio-smartphone-mini">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>250$</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <a class="comprar-smartphone-grande comprar-smartphone-mini" href="#">Comprar</a>
                
            </div>

        </main>

        <footer class="footer-grande footer-mini">
            
            <p class="p-grande p-mini">Todos los derechos reservados ©.</p>

                <p class="siguenos-mini mini">Siguenos en nuestras redes!</p>

            <a class="logofb-mini mini" title="Perfil de Tecnoven en Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/DAGF1712">
                <img class="logofb-mini mini" src="logofb.png" alt="Perfil de Tecnoven en Facebook"> </a>

            <a class="logoig-mini mini" title="Perfil de Tecnoven en Instagram" href="http://www.instagram.com/DAGF1712">
                <img class="logoig-mini mini" src="logoig.png" alt="Perfil de Tecnoven en Instagram"> </a>

        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: small-caps 100% serif;
}

.grande{ 
    display: none;
 }

 header-mini{
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 4vw solid #04c4a4;
    height: %;

 }

 .logo-mini{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
 }

 .lista-nav-mini{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

 .lista-nav-mini li{
    position: relative;
    left: 25%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    margin:2%;
}

.lista-nav-mini a{
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 10%;
    border:1px solid #04c4a4;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
 }

 .lista-nav-mini a:hover{
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 8px #999;
    background-color: #04c4a430;
 }

 .main-mini{
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.productos-nuevos-mini{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3vw;
}

.smartphones-mini{
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

.smartphone-mini {
    border: 3px solid #04c4a4;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: relative;
    left: 5%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 25%;
}

.titulo-smartphone-mini{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
}

.foto-smartphone-mini{
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 9%;
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
}

.precio-smartphone-mini{
    font-size: 3vw;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 65%;
    margin-top: 55%;
    text-align: center;
}

.comprar-smartphone-mini{
    font-size: 3vw;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 27%;
    margin-top: 58%;
    padding: 1.5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 25%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.comprar-smartphone-mini:hover {
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 8px #999;
    background-color: #04c4a430;
}

.footer-mini{
    background-color: black;
    height: 25%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.p-mini{
    font-size: 3vw;
    position: relative;
    top: 80%;
    right: 20%;
}

.siguenos-mini{
    font-size: 4vw;
}

.logofb-mini{
    width: 11%;
    position: relative;
}

.logoig-mini{
    width: 8.1%;
    position: relative;
    left: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}
```

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código, es imposible dar un porque sin ver el código. Saludos.

Comment: Acabo de ver el link que muestras la verdad no puedo ver el problema que comentas, seria mucho mejor si mostraras una captura para ver mejor el problema y obviamente adjuntes el código necesario para verificar donde se encuentra el error.

Comment: subido el codigo

Comment: ya tambien agrege captura para que vean a que me refiero

Comment: Al entrar en modo de diseño adaptable te añade `#fix { width: 25%;}` solo para las vistas móvil. En el código que pones no se ve el origen de este problema. Quizás sea parte de algún framework CSS que uses o en los scripts. Puede que esté en `styles_mini.css`

Comment: el unico codigo que esta subido es el publicado y el styles_mini.css es el codigo publicado. no se porque sigue teniendo ese problema

Comment: Buen website amigo, sin embargo, tu problema no sera solucionado con un par de lineas de codigo que te demos. Te recomiendo que estudies un poco mas css y html, especificamente buscate un tutorial sobre diseno web adaptable, en donde te ensenaran hacer un web que se adapte todos los tamanos de pantalla, ya sea iphone, tablet, laptop o desktop.

Comment: gracias por la recomendación, seguiré estudiando

Comment: El enlace no funciona. Por cierto, ¿resolviste tu problema?